# How to determine if a user has been subscribed before - RevenueCat

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable, revenuecat

I would like to be able to determine if a user has ever been subscribed to 
be able to change the name of the purchase button. In other words, at start the button will say, `Try It Now` if the user is currently subscribed the button will say `Subscribed` but if the user used to be subscribed but the subscription has been expired I want to display `Renew` on the purchase button.

Currently everything works except for the `Renew` option.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    Purchases.shared.purchaserInfo { (purchaserInfo, error) in
        self.configurePurchases(purchaserInfo: purchaserInfo)
    }
}

func configurePurchases(purchaserInfo: PurchaserInfo?) {
    if let purchaserInfo = purchaserInfo {
        if purchaserInfo.activeEntitlements.contains("myKillerFeatureEntitlement") {
            myButton.setTitle("Subscribed",for: .normal)
            labelAutoTaxDescription.text = "You are currently subscribed. Thank you for your support."

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

            if let expirationDate = purchaserInfo.expirationDate(forEntitlement: "myKillerFeatureEntitlement") {
                self.labelAutoTaxDetectionPrice.text = "Expiration Date: \(dateFormatter.string(from: expirationDate))"
            }
        }
    }

    // Here is where I need check if it's a returning user so I can change the name of the button
    if isReturningUser{

        myButton.setTitle("Renew",for: .normal)

        // other code
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to check if a user has been subscribed before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `allPurchasedProductIdentifiers NSSet<NSString *>` on the `RCPurchaserInfo` object to see all the product identifiers the user has purchased regardless of expiration date.

Alternatively, if you want to check for the "myKillerFeatureEntitlement" *entitlement* specifically, you can check the `purchaseDateForEntitlement` property. If the `activeEntitlements` is nil and there is a purchase date you can assume it was previously purchased then expired.

```swift
func configurePurchases(purchaserInfo: PurchaserInfo?) {
    if let purchaserInfo = purchaserInfo {
        if purchaserInfo.activeEntitlements.contains("myKillerFeatureEntitlement") {
            myButton.setTitle("Subscribed",for: .normal)
            labelAutoTaxDescription.text = "You are currently subscribed. Thank you for your support."

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

            if let expirationDate = purchaserInfo.expirationDate(forEntitlement: "myKillerFeatureEntitlement") {
                self.labelAutoTaxDetectionPrice.text = "Expiration Date: \(dateFormatter.string(from: expirationDate))"
            }

        // Here is where I need check if it's a returning user so I can change the name of the button
        } else if purchaserInfo.purchaseDate(forEntitlement: "myKillerFeatureEntitlement") != nil {

                myButton.setTitle("Renew",for: .normal)

                // other code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the entitlement could have been unlocked on another platform (Android, web, etc.) so the button on iOS may not actually be triggering a restore.

Comment: @ enc_life - Can you please clarify something about your second suggestion?  You are stating the following… *If the `activeEntitlements` is nil and there is a purchase date you can assume it was previously purchased then expired.* But in your code we are only checking if `purchaseDate` is not `nil` but not whether the entitlement is nil or not.
Sorry if I'm not seeing the obvious.

Comment: @fs_tigre I updated my answer to contain the full code sample. Let me know that that is more clear.